# "unloadwallet" and "notifywallet", work together?

Tags: wallet, wallet-notify

I couldn't understand it very well in the places I looked and in the documentation I read, and it would take about 1 month for me to have bitcoins to test, I thought it was better to ask here.

I will need to have multiple wallets, so I could understand the correct way to work with them would be using "loadwallet" before generating addresses and doing any action on the wallet, and if I were going to use another wallet I should do an "unloadwallet" and another "loadwallet " to continue.

But in a description I saw, when leaving the wallet unloaded the "walletnotify" would not work correctly until the "loadwallet" was used again.

So what would be the correct way to use multiwallets and have actions targeted to specific wallets?

Comment: You can load multiple wallets simultaneously; no need to load and unload every time you're going to use a wallet for something.

Comment: But, for example, when I call "getnewaddress", how can I target this to a specific wallet?

Comment: If you use `bitcoin-cli`, you specify the subject wallet with the `-rpcwallet=` command line argument. If you're using JSON-RPC directly, there is a separate URI for every wallet.

Comment: NICE, thanks so much, i understand now, its work!